# Horizontal unwanted scroll bar from CSS

Tags: html, css

I have no idea where from I get this horizontal bar in the bottom. I tried overflow: hidden; but that didn't work. I looked on the internet but most people recommend the same line that I wrote above.

I am not an expert in css, html or bootstrap. I know a little from each one. Somehow I made a mistake in my code.

Please someone tell me what I did wrong in CSS, HTML or Bootstrap.

CSS:

```css
body {
 background-color: #EEEEEE;

}
ul, ul li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}
.top-red-hr { 
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-style: inset;
    border: 4px solid #8C1113;
} 
.top-first-menu {
 width: 100%;
 display: table;

}
.top-first-menu .menu-right {
 float: right;
 padding: 20px 0 10px 0;
}
.top-second-menu {
 background: #000000;
}
.top-second-menu .logo {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 20px;
}
.top-second-menu .logo h1 {
 color: #961915;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 line-height: 0.8;
}
.top-second-menu .logo h1 span {
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
.top-second-menu .logo p {
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
.top-second-menu .top-red-buttons {
 display: inline-block;
}
.top-second-menu .top-red-buttons button{
 float: right;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
.top-second-menu .language-menu {
 display: inline-block;
}
.top-second-menu .top-red-buttons,
.top-second-menu .language-menu {
 padding-top: 28px;
}
.consulter-form form,
.consulter-form h2{
 background-color: #DFE3E4;
}
.consulter-form h2 {
 width: 70%;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 border: none;
}
.consulter-form form {
 margin-top: 0px;
 border-top: 1px solid #DFE3E4;
}
.vous-voulez-button {
 background-color: #DFE3E4;
 
}
.trouver-hr {
 width:100%;
 height:5px;
 display:block;
 margin-top:50px;
 background:#efefef;
 border-top:1px solid #CCC;
 border-bottom:1px solid #FFF;
}
.text-p, .vous-voulez {
 margin-top: 40px;
}
.rubrique-promo {

}
.rubrique {

}
.boxes-details {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 
}
.boxes-images {
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.boxes-images img {
 width: 100%;
}
.boxes-images h4 {
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #8C1211;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.boxes-images .details {
 background-color: #D6D6D6;
 border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:4px; 
}
.boxes-images .details-text {
 color: #8C1211;
 padding-top: 10px !important;
}
.boxes-images .details p {
 padding: 0px 10px;
}
.boxes-images .details p:last-child {
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.boxes-images .details p:nth-child(2) {
 border-top: 2px solid #AAAAAA;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #E5E0E0;
 padding: 7px 10px;
}
.boxes-images .details p span{
 float: right;
}
.bottom-hr-black {
 margin-top: 100px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

footer {
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.discount {
 text-align: center;
 background: #D6D6D6;
}
.discount p {
 line-height: 1.5;

}
.first-p-bottom {
 margin-top: 10px;
}
.bottom-black-hr {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-style: inset;
    border: 4px solid #444444;
}
.footer-lists {
 background-color: #444444;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
.list-links h4 {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
 text-align: left;
}

.list-links ul li {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #FAFBF9;
 color: #FAFBF9;
}
.list-links ul li a {
 color: #FAFBF9;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.copyright {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 30px 0px 10px 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
 <title>CLICK COOL</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 
</head>
<body>
<header>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="top-first-menu">
    <div class="btn-group menu-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active btn-lg">Espace clients</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active btn-lg">Promotions - Fin de series</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active btn-lg">Devenir partenaire</button>
   </div>
  </div><!-- end top-first-menu -->
  <div class="top-second-menu container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="logo col-md-5">
     <h1>CLICK<span>COOL</span></h1>
     <p>Le site ideal pour promouvoir vos activites</p>
    </div><!-- end logo -->
    <div class="top-red-buttons col-md-6">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">TARIF - SERVICES</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">CLICK CORPORATE</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">STANDARD SVI</button>
    </div><!-- end top-red-buttons -->
    <div class="language-menu col-md-1">
     <div class="form-group">
      <!-- <label for="sel1">Select list:</label> -->
       <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
          <option>En</option>
          <option>Fr</option>
          <option>Ch</option>
        </select>
     </div>
    </div><!-- end language-menu -->

   </div>
  </div><!-- end top-second-menu -->
  <hr class="top-red-hr">
 </div><!-- end container-fluid -->
</header>

<main class="container-fluid">
 <div class="home-top-selects">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="consulter-form col-sm-6">
             <h2>Consulter les petites annonces</h2>
             <form>
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-8">
                         <h4>Par mot-cle les petites annonces</h4>
                     </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-8">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-sm-4">
                         <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                             <option>Toutes categories</option>
                             <option>1</option>
                             <option>2</option>
                             <option>3</option>
                         </select>
                     </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-3">
                         <h4>Ou?</h4>
                     </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-3">
                         <select class="form-control" id="select-flags">
                             <option>En</option>
                             <option>Fr</option>
                             <option>Ch</option>
                         </select>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-sm-5">
                         <select class="form-control" id="another-select">
                             <option>toutes les villes select</option>
                         </select>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
                             Lancez Votre Recherche
                         </button>
                     </div>
                 </div>

                 <h5 class="text-info text-center">
                     Faite une recherche dans votre perimetre grace a votre geolocalisation.
                 </h4>
             </form>
         </div>

         <div class="consulter-form col-sm-6">
             <h2>Trouver Une Enterprise</h2>
             <form>
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-6">
                         <h4>Par mot-cle ou nom d'enterprise</h4>
                     </div>

                     <div class="col-sm-3">
                         <h4>Ou?</h4>
                     </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-6">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr-2" />
                     </div>

                     <div class="col-sm-3">
                         <select class="form-control" id="another-select-2">
                             <option>Toutes les villes select</option>
                         </select>
                     </div>

                     <div class="col-sm-3">
                         <select class="form-control" id="select-flags-2">
                             <option>En</option>
                             <option>Fr</option>
                             <option>Ch</option>
                         </select>
                     </div>
                 </div>

                 <!-- Place this to fill the blank space -->
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-12">
                         <h4>&#160;</h4>
                     </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-6">
                         <select class="form-control" id="different-select">
                             <option>Autres options de recherche</option>
                         </select>
                     </div>

                     <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-3">
                         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
                             Chercher
                         </button>
                     </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="trouver-hr"></div>

                 <div class="text-center">
                     <h3 class="text-info">
                         Votre enterprise n'est pas referencee?
                     </h3>
                     <button class="btn btn-large btn-default">
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> AJOUTER MON ENTERPRISE 
                     </button>
                 </div>
             </form>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>

 <div class="vous-voulez ">
  <div class="row"> 
   <div class="consulter-form col-sm-6">         
          <h4>Vous voulez vendre votre bien rapidement?</h4>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Cliquez ici pour une annonce gratuitement!</button>                          
         </div>
         <div class="consulter-form col-sm-6">         
          <h4>Recherche par numero de telephone</h4>
             <form>
              <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" />  
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">CHERCHER</button>
               </div>
              </div>  
             </form>
         </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="text-p">
  <div class="row"> 
   <div class="col-sm-6">         
             <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-9">
               <p>Cliquez sur l'une des icones suivantes pour masquer la recherche</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="false"></span></button>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
              </div>
             </div>  
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">   
             <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-9">
               <p>Aimeriez-vous promouvoir votre actiuvite ou produit? <a href="#">Consultez nos tarifs</a>
              </div>
             </div> 
         </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="text-p">
  <div class="row"> 
   <div class="col-sm-1">         
             <img src="#"><p>PUB</p>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-11">   
             <div class="row">
              <img src="images/Calque-6e.png">
             </div> 
         </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="text-p">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-5 text-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">Toutes les petites announces</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-7 text-right">
    <p>Petites announces gratuites aujourd'hui avec plus de 10'000 announces</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="text-p text-center">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">Automobilies &amp; Accesories</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">Immobiliers  &amp; Prestige</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">Emploi &amp; Carrieres</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">Hotel &amp; Restaurant</button>
   </div> 
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="text-p rubrique-promo">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4 rubrique">
    <h3>Rubrique</h3>
    <ul>
     <li>ANIMAUX &amp; ACCESSOIRES </li>
     <li>ART &amp; ANTIQUITES</li>
     <li>AUTOMOBILES</li>
     <li>BIJOUTERIE</li>
     <li>BRICOLAGES &amp; JARDINAGE</li>
     <li>COLLECTIONS</li>
     <li>EMPLOI</li>
     <li>ENFANTS</li>
     <li>ENFANTS &amp; BEBE</li>
     <li>IMMOBILIER</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-7">
    <img src="images/promo.jpg">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="text-p boxes-details">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-3 boxes-images">
    <img src="images/automobile.jpg">
    <h4>IMMOBILIER</h4>
    <div class="details">
     <p class="details-text">Magnifique et spacieux 4,5 pieces: 1mios de loyer</p>
     <p>Lieu<span>suchy</span><p>
     <p>Prix<span>CHF 2'250</span></p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 boxes-images">
    <img src="images/automobile.jpg">
    <h4>IMMOBILIER</h4>
    <div class="details">
     <p class="details-text">Magnifique et spacieux 4,5 pieces: 1mios de loyer</p>
     <p>Lieu<span>suchy</span><p>
     <p>Prix<span>CHF 2'250</span></p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 boxes-images">
    <img src="images/automobile.jpg">
    <h4>IMMOBILIER</h4>
    <div class="details">
     <p class="details-text">Magnifique et spacieux 4,5 pieces: 1mios de loyer</p>
     <p>Lieu<span>suchy</span><p>
     <p>Prix<span>CHF 2'250</span></p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 boxes-images">
    <img src="images/automobile.jpg">
    <h4>IMMOBILIER</h4>
    <div class="details">
     <p class="details-text">Magnifique et spacieux 4,5 pieces: 1mios de loyer</p>
     <p>Lieu<span>suchy</span><p>
     <p>Prix<span>CHF 2'250</span></p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 boxes-images">
    <img src="images/automobile.jpg">
    <h4>IMMOBILIER</h4>
    <div class="details">
     <p class="details-text">Magnifique et spacieux 4,5 pieces: 1mios de loyer</p>
     <p>Lieu<span>suchy</span><p>
     <p>Prix<span>CHF 2'250</span></p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 boxes-images">
    <img src="images/automobile.jpg">
    <h4>IMMOBILIER</h4>
    <div class="details">
     <p class="details-text">Magnifique et spacieux 4,5 pieces: 1mios de loyer</p>
     <p>Lieu<span>suchy</span><p>
     <p>Prix<span>CHF 2'250</span></p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 boxes-images">
    <img src="images/automobile.jpg">
    <h4>IMMOBILIER</h4>
    <div class="details">
     <p class="details-text">Magnifique et spacieux 4,5 pieces: 1mios de loyer</p>
     <p>Lieu<span>suchy</span><p>
     <p>Prix<span>CHF 2'250</span></p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 boxes-images">
    <img src="images/automobile.jpg">
    <h4>IMMOBILIER</h4>
    <div class="details">
     <p class="details-text">Magnifique et spacieux 4,5 pieces: 1mios de loyer</p>
     <p>Lieu<span>suchy</span><p>
     <p>Prix<span>CHF 2'250</span></p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div col-sm-12>
   <div class="bottom-black-hr">
  </div>
 </div>
 
 

 <div class="discount">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12 footer-p">
    <p class="first-p-bottom">Le depot d'annonces, inclus 10 photos et 5 videos.</p>
    <p>4 devises proposees: CHF, EURO, USD, GBP / Pour vendre, acheter, fournir vos presentations</p>    
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</main>
<footer class="footer-lists container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 list-links">
   <h4>A propos</h4>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#" title="#">Qui somme nous</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="#">Relations investisseurs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="#">Clickcool pour particuliers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="#">Clickcool pour professionnels</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 list-links">
   <h4>Utilitaries</h4>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#" title="#">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="#">Partners links</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="#">Regles de diffusion</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="#">Infos legales et CGU</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 list-links">
   <h4>Liens utile</h4>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#" title="#">Tarifs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="#">Concept</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="#">Publicite</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="#">Formulaire de contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 list-links">
   <img src="images/Calque-52-text.png">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 copyright">
   <p>Copyright &copy; 2015-106. Tous droits reserves</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to only post the relevant part of the problem. Not your entire code. Most people don't have time to look through all that

Comment: Do you have a working example of your site? also what is the screen size you are testing in?

Comment: I have it only on local and it is the same problem for all screen sizes

Comment: @duxfox I'm sory but I don't know where from is comming. That's why I put the whole code.

Comment: @SorinDragomir Right solution is to add `col-sm-12` class to `<div class="discount">`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38637213/4306572
You mark as correct wrong answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add overflow:hidden to body, it works

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

`.row` classes will have margin-left, margin-right has -15px, so it will cause the scroll bar. You better to wrap `.row` elements in `.container` class or you need to wrap `.row` elememts with another parent element which should have padding of 15px

Comment: when I use this rule I can't scroll down the page anymore.

Comment: give overflow-x: hidden only

Comment: It is a hack. Right solution has @AlexM http://stackoverflow.com/a/38637213/4306572

Comment: if there will be the cases should not using of col-* classes, at that time, what you will do

Comment: Div with class `row` must contain some div/divs with `col-*` class. That was error. Your solution doesn't fix the reason of this bug.

Comment: check this example, i have added col-* under row, but its not working...https://jsfiddle.net/Nageshwar521/zr900y50/

Comment: Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Fix your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/y8k3qwv0/

Comment: that answer is not telling in that way right, before telling, u should analyze yourself

Comment: you told adding col-* is enough for the fix..you should check yourself before giving downvote

Comment: @NageshwarReddy Adding `col-` class is enough for the problem described in the question above. If you look at HTML you will notice `<div class="top-second-menu container-fluid">`.

Comment: @NageshwarReddy I added detailed answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/38637085/4306572 `overflow:hidden` isn't solution.

Answer (score 1):

At first there are some markup errors. See line 100 - opening h5 tag, closing h4 tag. Perhaps there are much more errors. So we don't know is html rendered correctly.

Let's run the snippet and look at its code in console.

[image]

We can see that block `discount` and block without class (with attr `col-sm-12`) are placed in block `row`. So adding class `col-*` to `discount` seems to be good solution to solve problem with horizontal scrolling.

> According [bootstrap greed docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), row item must contain col items.

But let's open raw code:

[image]

Block `discount` isn't place in `row`. It can mean only one - there are errors in documents markup. Look at line 363 - there isn't closing `</div>` tag. Fix it and run code - it seems all works fine. But lets add class `col-sm-12` to the div at 362 line instead attribute. Brilliant! We fix all errors!

---

**Summary.**

Line 100: fix  closing tag of `h5`.

Line 362: replace attribute `col-sm-12` by class `col-sm-12`.

Line 363: add closing tag for `div`.

Comment: no need of this much big answer, tell in simple and smart way..that looks great

Comment: I just wanted to describe in detail how to find the problem in the code.

Comment: its a small one, u shouldn't argue for accepting answer, if he ur answer helps, definetely will mart it as answer..try to give best answer for solution not for votes

Comment: I think @Alex M gave better solution than yours. He was closer to the problem. I voted for his answer and disliked yours. Then I decided to find a real problem. I don't understand the cause of our quarrel.

Comment: you both are at one place..the way of following is quite wrong

Comment: if the QP likes definetely makes your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following trick:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

But it's a hack.

To go further add `col-sm-12` class to `<div class="discount">`.

Comment: its not working, check here https://jsfiddle.net/Nageshwar521/zr900y50/

Comment: i want the full-width page, if i add container, it wont look like full width right

Comment: @NageshwarReddy Use `.container-fluid` for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport. Look at the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container).

Answer (score 0):

If you just change container-fluid to container it will work as well. But it will not span the whole width..